# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__bases__'

Tags: python, flask, flask-superadmin

I found a program online to help me learn python better, and I was reading through it when I came accross this error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__bases__'
```

Here is the traceback: https://gist.github.com/2984652f5c4ed99607e286799929a0f1

Could anyone here help me on how to debug/fix my issue? Or at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please put a [mcve] **in the question**. Also, could you put a *question* in the question.

Comment: Yeah i would but i dont know where the error is coming from lol

Comment: Then start narrowing that down; SO isn't here to do basic debugging for you.

Comment: Its a very big project, ive tried quite a lot, and also could you tell me how to edit the post? quite new here lol 
edit: nvm, figured it out

Comment: *"Could anyone here help me on how to debug/fix my issue? or atleast point me in the right direction?"* - no, SO isn't a tutorial service. Read [ask], and e.g. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: How did u end up with that message?, What were you exactly running?, Where is your sample code relative to that error?